# Chart.js: scrollable/swipable time-based x-axis

Tags: chart.js

Let's say I have the following data set using a *time based Cartesian x axis*. Basically, these are data points spread over 3 days.

```
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 5, 0, 0), y: 9},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 5, 2, 0), y: 7},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 5, 5.5, 0), y: 4.3},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 5, 7, 0), y: 6},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 5, 8, 0), y: 3.7},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 5, 14, 0), y: 9.5},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 6, 4, 0), y: 4.0},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 6, 11, 0), y: 5},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 6, 12, 0), y: 2.7},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 6, 14, 0), y: 1.7},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 6, 19, 0), y: 5.7},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 7, 17, 0), y: 6.7},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 7, 21, 0), y: 5.7},
    {x: new Date(2021, 2, 7, 22, 0), y: 4.7},
```

Lets say my starting view is the middle day, in this case day 6. Then I want a feature where you can swipe scroll to the next / previous day. Only 1 day should be shown in the graph at a time, unless you are scrolling / swiping between these.

Here is a simple sketch to illustrate this using the above data points.

[image]

Here are some other examples that show what I mean:

1. https://swipecalendar.io/. While this is a calendar, the idea should be clear and applicable to a line graph as well. You are swiping between 'months' and snapping to a month.
2. https://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-data/. Here you can see you can swipe along the x-axis and the time-span of the x-axis changes along while swiping (ignoring the 'full' graph' they have on the bottom).

Is something like this possible with Chartjs or with a plugin? I have not see any Chartjs examples that have a changing chart view based on a scroll state of the x-axis.
If not, is there recommendation for an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this plugin, https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom

With this you can make the chart movable

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I came across the plugin already, and only focused on the zoom part, not realizing the panning / changing x-axis/y-axis while swiping is also part of the plugin. And it works great. There is no 'snapping' feature though, but seems like it can be extended to support that.